# Javascript & HTML: Make onmouseover work for div NOT in foreground?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover

I have a collection of divs arranged in such a manner:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="background"></div>
   <div id="foreground">
       <div id="foreground_element1></div>
       <div id="foreground_element2></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The background div has to be behind the foreground div. And the background div is larger that the foreground; the foreground floats on top of it. What I want to do is whenever there is an onmouseover action for the background div, I want to run my JavaScript function.

The problem I have is that the onmouseover isn't signaled if the mouse is on the area of the foreground, even though the background div still exists in that space, it's just behind the foreground. This is an issue.

I have tried to work around it by putting my desired function on the main div mouseover, but when the mouse moves from the background div to the foreground div, there is a mouseout and mouseover event called simultaneously, which makes my function run twice when I only want it to run once. And there are even more complications because the foreground div has nested elements as well which once again trigger a mouseout and mouseover combo.

Is there any way to make the onmouseover work for the entirety of the background div? Or is there some other trigger I should be using?

Comment: `onmouseenter`, but make sure the browsers you want to support have implemented it

Comment: can't you make #foreground a child of #background? and then position it in absolute instead of floating it.

Comment: I don't think onmouseenter would be a good solution since it's not officially compatible with any browser other than microsoft. I can try to make the foreground a child, but I would prefer not to do that if possible

Answer (score 0):

I actually luckily found the answer to my own question online :) Posting it here for other's to reference:

As someone mentioned in the comments above, the Microsoft function onMouseEnter does what I'm looking for. The problem is that it's not widely supported by other browsers. But you can write a JavaScript function to emulate it, as described here: http://dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/isMouseLeaveOrEnter/